# Preview pixel value for float-image

Tags: image, opencv, ros

Say I have a floating point image, e.g. in 32FC1 format for a thermal image, and I want to display it using (preferably) ROS or openCV tools, while also being able to see the current pixel value (e.g. temperature) my mouse is hovering over. How would I do that? Rviz can display the image, but will not show any pixel values. Image_view is also able to display the image, but will show the pixel value in RGB.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// create a global Mat
cv::Mat img_32FC1;

// function to be called on mouse event
// displays values on console, it can be modified to print values on image
void mouseEventCallBack (int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *userdata)
{
  if(event == cv::EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)
  {
    cout<<"x = "<<x<<", y = "<<y<<" value = "<<img_32FC1.at<float>(y,x)<<endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  // original color image, CV_8UC3
  cv::Mat img_8UC3 = cv::imread("image.jpg",cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED), img_8UC1;

  // convert original image to gray, CV_8UC1
  cv::cvtColor(img_8UC3, img_8UC1, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

  // convert to float, CV_32FC1
  img_8UC1.convertTo(img_32FC1, CV_32FC1);
  img_32FC1 /= 255.0;

  // create a window
  cv::namedWindow("window",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

  // set MouseCallback function
  cv::setMouseCallback("window", mouseEventCallBack);

  // Display image
  cv::imshow("window", img_8UC1);
  cv::waitKey(0);
  cv::destroyAllWindows();
  return 0;
}
```